# Need an "if/else" statement for my sql file upload Please

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I am building a rather large database and I upload using a sql file. Unfortunately my sql file contains duplicates of items already in the database. So here is my question, is there a way to use an "if / else" statement in my sql to say if url in column url exists then UPDATE else INSERT.

How would I write it at the top of my sql file? It is hard to define because my data being uploaded looks like this... I will be adding more columns once I get this part figured out.

I want to AVOID my database from having duplicate URL's in the URL column. But I want to be able to keep the info fresh so it needs to be able to update if URL is already in the database.

Sorry about long explanation, Does anyone know the code to put at the top of the sql file to allow the if else upload? In short "if" it exists then UPDATE "else" INSERT

('http://ikarga.net/' ,'200'),

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL's [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replace.html) which will do INSERT/UPDATE for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the functions [`INSERT IGNORE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html) or [`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) for this.++

In your case the `IGNORE` function is the best. It ignores errors and then skips the row. Note: All errors for that INSERT will be ignored.